# Extending/Overriding base JavaScript in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend

AFAIK, the `mage.confirm` widget is defined in this file:

`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js`

I'm looking to override the file in my theme to provide alternative default behaviour for confirm modals (e.g. the one displayed in M2 when removing an item from the minicart).

I've tried to customise the widget following the steps in the FE dev docs without success. Is it possible to override this base file?

Comment: Did you get the solution for your question, if ok please send the answer

Answer (score 3):

You could locate this file in you theme. As your original file is in:

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js

Then create a folder:

> app/design/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Ui/web/js/modal/confirm.js

This file will be catched during static-content deployment

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
map: {
  '*': {
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm":  "Vendor_Module/js/your-js-module"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where i have to keep this code, Please let me know the file location

Comment: In the main root of your theme: <Vendor>/<Theme>/requirejs-config.js

Comment: "Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm":  "Vendor_Module/js/your-js-module"

Comment: what is this "your-js-module"

Comment: which module i have to give here

Comment: "your-js-module" is your overrided mage.confirm. Ex. if your customizations are located in your theme, in a file named confirm-custom.js in your requrejs-config map you have to put:

"Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm": "js/confirm-custom"

Comment: 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm.js': 'Ewall_restaurant/js/modal/confirm'

Comment: i have tried like above, but confirm.js calling from vendor only

Comment: @shivashankarm, Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding it by:

> code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/base/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm':'[Vendor]_[Module]/js/modal/confirm'
        }
    }
};
```

> code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, _, $t) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.confirm', $.mage.modal, {
        options: {
            modalClass: 'confirm',
            title: '',
            focus: '.action-accept',
            actions: {

                /**
                 * Callback always - called on all actions.
                 */
                always: function () {},

                /**
                 * Callback confirm.
                 */
                confirm: function () {},

                /**
                 * Callback cancel.
                 */
                cancel: function () {}
            },
            buttons: [{
                text: $t('Cancel'),
                class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',

                /**
                 * Click handler.
                 */
                click: function (event) {
                    this.closeModal(event);
                }
            }, {
                text: $t('OK'),
                class: 'action-primary action-accept',

                /**
                 * Click handler.
                 */
                click: function (event) {
                    this.closeModal(event, true);
                }
            }]
        },

        /**
         * Create widget.
         */
        _create: function () {
            this._super();
            this.modal.find(this.options.modalCloseBtn).off().on('click', _.bind(this.closeModal, this));
            this.openModal();
        },

        /**
         * Remove modal window.
         */
        _remove: function () {
            this.modal.remove();
        },

        /**
         * Open modal window.
         */
        openModal: function () {
            return this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Close modal window.
         */
        closeModal: function (event, result) {
            result = result || false;

            if (result) {
                this.options.actions.confirm(event);
            } else {
                this.options.actions.cancel(event);
            }
            this.options.actions.always(event);
            this.element.on('confirmclosed', _.bind(this._remove, this));

            return this._super();
        }
    });

    return function (config) {
        return $('<div></div>').html(config.content).confirm(config);
    };
});
```